# How to release a locked row using JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, locking, eclipselink, pessimistic

I'm using the EclipseLink implementation of the JPA 2.0 which allows pessimistic locking.  I know how to lock an entity but how do I release the lock?  At first I thought this was all taken care of within a transaction (in other words, the entity is locked until you commit the transaction), but that does not seem to be the case.

I tried a quick google search (seems like this should be pretty obvious), but I haven't found anything...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After getting some sleep... and doing some more testing in the morning, I believe I have figured out my problem.

So the lock is actually `taken care of within a transaction`. However, when I was testing my code, I was able to retrieve a locked row using the `EntityManager.find(Class, key)` method (no locking strategy specified).

I erroneously thought that by putting a lock on a row, the row could not be read, period.  However, I reread the JPA definitions of `PESSIMISTIC_READ` and `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` and noticed my problem:

> PESSIMISTIC_READ - The Entity is locked on the database, prevents any other transaction from **acquiring a PESSIMISTIC_WRITE lock.**
>   PESSIMISTIC_WRITE - The Entity is locked on the database, prevents any other transaction from **acquiring a PESSIMISTIC_READ or PESSIMISTIC_WRITE lock.**

The **lock** doesn't necessarily prevent all reads, it just prevents another transaction from putting a `READ or WRITE lock` on the row.